# Why the Expo Go exit when I refresh my app on this eidt screen only?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, expo

I'm using Expo Go app on my device to run my app and everything is working properly except edit screen when I want to refresh Expo Go app the Expo shut down by itself only on edit screen and on other screens, I can smoothly refresh without exiting from the expo go app.

Here is my Edit screen code:

```
import firebase from "firebase";
import {db,auth} from '../../firebase'


const EditProfile=({navigation})=>{

  const sheetRef = React.createRef(null);
  const animated = new Animated.Value(1);
  const [image, setImage] = useState(null);
  const [uploading,setUploading] = useState(false)
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState(null);



  React.useEffect(()=>{
    const getUserData = async()=>{

      db.collection("users")
      .doc(auth.currentUser?.uid)
      .get()
      .then(snap => {
      
          setUserData(snap.data());
        
      });
    }
    getUserData();
  },[])



  const updateProfile = async()=>{
    let imgUrl = await uploadImage();
    if(imgUrl == null && userData.userImg){
     imgUrl = userData.userImg
    }

    db.collection("users")
    .doc(auth.currentUser.uid)
    .set({
      name: userData.name,
      email: userData.email,
      phone: userData.phone,
      address: userData.address,
      userImg:userData.imgUrl
      
  })
  }


  {/*upload Image to firebase sotrage*/}

   const uploadImage = async ()=>{
      if(image == null){
        return "";
      }
      const blob = await new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onload = function (){
           resolve(xhr.response)
        };
        xhr.onerror = function (){
            reject( new TypeError("Network request failed"))

        };
        xhr.responseType = "blob"
        xhr.open("GET",image,true)
        xhr.send(null)
      });
      const ref = firebase.storage().ref().child("images/" + new Date().toISOString())
      const snapshot = ref.put(blob)

      snapshot.on(
        firebase.storage.TaskEvent.STATE_CHANGED,
        ()=>{
            setUploading(true)
        },
        (error)=>{
            setUploading(false)
            console.log(error)
            blob.close();
            return ;
        },
        ()=>{
            snapshot.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then((url)=>{
              
              setUserData({...userData, imgUrl: url})
              setUploading(false);
               // Alert.alert('Profile Updated', 'You profile Updated Successfully..!')
                console.log('donwload:', url)
                blob.close()
                return null
            })
        }
      )
   
    
       
    
     }


   {/*Render COntent for Bottom Sheet*/}
   const renderContent=()=>{
    return(
      <View style={style.panel}>
      <View>
        <Text>Upload Photo</Text>
        <Text>Choose Your Profile Picture</Text>
      </View>

      <AppButton
       label='Take Photo'
      
      onPress={OpenCamera}
      />

       <AppButton
       label='Choose from Library'
      
       onPress={pickImage}
      />
     
     <AppButton
       label='Cancel'
       
       onPress={() => sheetRef.current.snapTo(1)}
      />
     
    </View>
    )
  }
     
   {/*Render Header For Bottom Sheet*/}
   const renderHeader=()=>{
    return(
      <View style={style.header}>
      <View style={style.panelHeader}>
        <View style={style.panelHandle} />
      </View>
    </View>
    )
  }


   {/*Pick Image Function*/}
const pickImage = async () => {

const {granted} = await ImagePicker.requestMediaLibraryPermissionsAsync()
if (!granted){
Alert.alert("Donate", 'You need to enable permission from the settings  to access the camera..!')
return;
}
let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
allowsEditing: true,
aspect: [4, 3],
quality: 1,
onPress:sheetRef.current.snapTo(1)
});

console.log(result);

if (!result.canceled) {
setImage(result.assets[0].uri);

}

}; 
  {/*Open Camera to take Pic*/}
  const OpenCamera = async () => {
  //permissions request is necessary for Openning Camera
  const {granted} = await ImagePicker.requestCameraPermissionsAsync()
   if (!granted){
    Alert.alert("Donation", 'You need to enable permission from the settings to access the camera..!')
    return ;
   }
  let result = await ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync({
    mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
    allowsEditing: true,
    aspect: [4, 3],
    quality: 1,
    onPress:sheetRef.current.snapTo(1)
  });

  console.log(result);

  if (!result.cancelled) {
    setImage(result.uri);
  }
};
```

I really don't know why only on Edit Profile screen the Expo Go app exit when I refresh my app on it, but when I do refresh my app on different screen like home screen the Expo Go app refreshing smoothly without exit from the app or shut it down and open it again. Any idea about this issue please do help me thank you.